# Five posts from a category in footer

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination, query-posts, categories

I am trying to show 5 posts from a category in my home footer.  I have placed this code

```
<?php query_posts( 'category_name=entertainment&posts_per_page=5' ); ?>
```

right in my `home.php` file and everything works fine except more than 5 posts are showing. In fact it is showing all the posts from that category. I have also tried `showposts=5` but still it is not working.

this is the full code in my `home.php`

```
    <?php query_posts( 'category_name=entertainment&posts_per_page=5' ); ?>
 <?php
if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) { die(); }
if (CFCT_DEBUG) { cfct_banner(__FILE__); }

if (have_posts()) {
    echo '<ul class="disclosure table group">';
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
?>
    <li>
<?php

        if(has_post_thumbnail())
{ the_post_thumbnail();}    cfct_excerpt();

?>
    </li>
<?php
    }
    echo '<li class="pagination">', cfct_misc('nav-list'),'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First: [don't use `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). Second: use [`$wp_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) instead:

```
$args = array (
  'category_name' => 'entertainment',
  'posts_per_page'=> 5
  );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    }
else {
    // no posts found
    }
```

Comment: please add the full code with the  $wp_query. And because i want to get the design of my post page. i copied the whole of my loop under this code <?php query_posts( 'category_name=entertainment&posts_per_page=5' ); ?>

Comment: That is the full code. You'll have to adapt the loop yourself according to your design.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function. With below code you'll get 5 post object-

```
$args = array (
  'category_name' => 'entertainment',
  'posts_per_page'=> 5
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Here at `$posts` variable you'll get the 5 posts.

Comment: could you please add the full code with the get function

Comment: That is the full code. In `$posts` you'll get an array of post objects. then run a `foreach` loop to show the post as you want. Better do a `print_r` on `$posts` and examine the structure. Then replace it with `foreach` loop.

Comment: did not work. maybe am not doing something right. i copied the post and pasted in my footer/home.php file. seriously am sorry but am a newbie in this. where exactly and how should i place the code in my file